# Needed to replace int with int array

Tags: c#, linq

I have been struggling to update below query since yesterday but no luck.

In below query I needed to replace `int idSiteno` with `int[] SelectedidSiteno` - you see replacing int with int array.

I tried with `.Contains` `.Any` almost everything but no way near the solution. Could you please help here.

```
ICollection<Department> dbList = _db.Departments
                                 .Include(l => l.Sites)
                                 .Where(l => l.idCompany == idCompany && l.Disabled == "N" 
                                             && l.Sites.Any(x => x.idSite == idSiteno))
                                 .OrderBy(l => l.SortOrder).ToList();
```

Comment: what do you want to query?

Comment: Do you want to use a query similar to the `Where Id IN (select ...` of SQL?

Comment: My query will be to extract all the data from department table where company id matches and all idsite's of sites collection matches  for all the selected id's in SelectedidSiteno

Answer (score 5):

So the contains does not work?

```
ICollection<Department> dbList = _db.Departments
.Include(l => l.Sites)
.Where(l => l.idCompany == idCompany && l.Disabled == "N" && l.Sites.Any(x => SelectedidSiteno.Contains(x.idSite)))
.OrderBy(l => l.SortOrder).ToList();
```

Comment: @GagandeepSinghRandhawa please upvote/mark as answer if this answer helped you

Comment: @MarcusH Right answer +1. However it seems the OP is not familiar with voting and accepting, based on his profile and his other questions unfortunately.

Comment: @S.Akbari you are a true hero! To bad there are so many who just take answers and don't have the mannors to accept

Comment: Sorry to spoil the party, but I don't think this is what OP asked for. I *think* they want `Department`s with only `Sites` that match a couple of ids. Yet another incarnation of the filtered Include question...

Comment: @GertArnold when I read the OPs first comment on my answer I think he was satisfied..but who knows

Answer (score 0):

> All the data from department table where company id matches and **all** idsite's of sites collection matches for **all** the selected id's in SelectedidSiteno

You can use `All` to check if every entry matches an specific expression. For example if all sites of an department match the `selected collection`.

```
ICollection<Department> dbList = _db.Departments
    .Include(l => l.Sites)
    .Where(l => l.idCompany == idCompany && 
        l.Disabled == "N" && 
        SelectedidSiteno.All(x => l.Sites.Any(s => s.idSite == x)))
    .OrderBy(l => l.SortOrder).ToList();
```